# Mouse Highlighting Interfering with HTML5 Game

Tags: html, canvas, mouse, highlight

So, having a lot of fun with HTML5 Canvas gaming. One issue, however, is if I am using DOM elements in addition to the canvas elements, clicking and dragging on the canvas will highlight and "select" DOM elements. A subsequent click operation will start to "drag" the DOM elements around instead of registering to the Canvas.

It's EXTREMELY annoying, and I cannot find a good way to prevent it. Is there a way to make DOM elements "not highlight-able" as it were? Anyone else having this issue?

Addenda: The game is a shooter, so you could hold the mouse click down to keep shooting. But your health and points are stored inside DOM elements. I could render the score/health to the canvas, but it was just faster to do it to a DOM element.

Comment: css rules to stop highlighting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/685404 ,apply this css to the canvas :)

Answer (score 2):

In your mousedown/click event handlers, add event.preventDefault() / return false.

**example**

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, false);
```